# bash: loop through procces output and terminate the process

Tags: linux, bash, command, ubuntu-12.04, output

I need some help with the following:

I use linux to script commands sent to a device. I need to submit a grep logcat command to the device and then iterate its output as it is being generated and look for a particular string. Once this string is found I want my script to move to the following command.

in pseudocode

```
for line in "adb shell logcat | grep TestProccess"
do 
    if "TestProccess test service stopped" in line:
       print line
       print "TestService finished \n"
       break
    else:
       print line
done
```

Answer (score 5):

```
adb shell logcat | grep TestProcess | while read line
do
  echo "$line"
  if [ "$line" = "TestProces test service stopped" ]
  then echo "TestService finished"
       break
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell logcat | grep -Fqm 1 "TestProcess test service stopped" && echo "Test Service finished"
```

The `grep` flags:

1. `-F` - treat the string literally, not as a regular expression
2. `-q` - don't print anything to standard output
3. `-m 1` - stop after the first match

The command after `&&` only executes if `grep` finds a match. As long as you "know" `grep` will eventually match and want to unconditionally continue once it returns, just leave off the `&& ...`

Comment: Works very well, many thanks for your contribution, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an until loop.

```
adb shell logcat | grep TestProccess | until read line && [[ "$line" =~ "TestProccess test service stopped" ]]; do
 echo $line;
done && echo -n "$line\nTestService finished"
```